# What does "let oneself out" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I have stumbled upon the phrase in the 21th episode of the 8th season of *Friends*. Here is the [scene](https://youtu.be/36LxvgdFZxo). It's at around 1 minute and 56 seconds.

> Phoebe: All right, all right, we’ll just do our best. Okay? So let’s
> say I’m the interviewer and I’m meeting you for the first time. Okay.
> "Hi! Come on in, I’m uh, Regina Philange."
>
> Chandler: Chandler Bing.
>
> Phoebe: Bing, what an unusual name.
>
> Chandler: Well you should meet my uncle, Bada. (Pause) I’ll **let myself
> out**.

Comment: This question has little to do with the language, other than that "ba-da bing" can be a spoken representation of a [rim shot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CdVTCDdEwI).  Uncle Bada Bing counts as a low-quality joke, and so a reason to not bother with the rest of the simulated interview.  He's already made a bad impression.  "I'll let myself out" suggests that he's leaving the interview of his own accord, before he finds himself *escorted* out.

Comment: Brits may say ["I'll get my coat"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3OM2MA1pic) in that situation.